# Flatten nested dictionary to key/value pairs with Ansible

Tags: dictionary, ansible, nested, jinja2

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    mydict:
      key1: val1
      key2: val2
      key3:
        subkey1: subval1
        subkey2: subval2
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ TODO }}"
```

How would I make the above debug message print out all key/value pairs from the nested dictionary? Assume the depth is unknown. I would expect the output to be something like:

```json
{
  "key1": "val1",
  "key2": "val2",
  "subkey1": "subval1"
  "subkey2": "subval2"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write a [filter plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_plugins.html) and use [pandas.json_normalize](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html?highlight=json_normalize), e.g.

```py
shell> cat filter_plugins/dict_normalize.py 
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

def dict_normalize(d):
    df = json_normalize(d)
    l = [df.columns.values.tolist()] + df.values.tolist()
    return(l)

class FilterModule(object):
    def filters(self):
        return {
            'dict_normalize': dict_normalize,
        }
```

The filter returns lists of keys and values

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        mlist: "{{ mydict|dict_normalize }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  mlist:
  - - key1
    - key2
    - key3.subkey1
    - key3.subkey2
  - - val1
    - val2
    - subval1
    - subval2
```

Create a dictionary, e.g.

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ dict(mlist.0|zip(mlist.1)) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg:
    key1: val1
    key2: val2
    key3.subkey1: subval1
    key3.subkey2: subval2
```

If the subkeys are unique remove the path

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ dict(_keys|zip(mlist.1)) }}"
      vars:
        _regex: '^(.*)\.(.*)$'
        _replace: '\2'
        _keys: "{{ mlist.0|map('regex_replace', _regex, _replace)|list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg:
    key1: val1
    key2: val2
    subkey1: subval1
    subkey2: subval2
```

**Notes**

- Install the package, e.g. [python3-pandas](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/python3-pandas)
- The filter might be extended to support all parameters of json_normalize
- The greedy regex works also in nested dictionaries

---

Q: *"**Turn the key3.subkey1 to get the original dictionary.**"*

A: Use *json_query*. For example, given the dictionary created in the first step

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        mydict_flat: "{{ dict(mlist.0|zip(mlist.1)) }}"
```

```yaml
  mydict_flat:
    key1: val1
    key2: val2
    key3.subkey1: subval1
    key3.subkey2: subval2
```

iterate the keys and retrieve the values from *mydict*

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ mydict|json_query(item) }}"
      loop: "{{ mydict_flat|list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: val1
  msg: val2
  msg: subval1
  msg: subval2
```

Comment: I didn't think about the uniqueness of the keys until reading your answer. My final goal was to search through the values and modify certain ones in place based on some criteria and I'll need the full path to do that. Would you know of a quick way to turn the `key3.subkey1` back into something that can be used in the original dict? For example: `mydict['key3']['subkey1']`

Comment: Sure, I've updated the answer. But, I'm not sure about the use case. In particular, there is no difference between "mydict|json_query(item)" and "mydict_flat[item]". Open a new question with the [mre] if you have more issues.